# Did Visual Studio 2012 have the data diagram?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, view, web, visual-studio-2012

I have changed my computer's name and my username, and got an error in Visual Studio 2010 when I tried to use data diagram. Today I installed Visual Studio 2012 and found that there is no "Data Diagram" at all. My question is, was there the "Data Diagram" in Visual Studio 2012 in the original installation? Did I corrupt it by changing my computer and user identities?

Anyone who has installed Visual Studio 2012 please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question,but i may found the real answer to my question.
[this page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735451/missing-database-diagram-node-in-server-explorer) said:

> I'm testing Visual Studio 11 with SQL 2012. I've created a LocaDB and connect in VS11 to Server Explorer. No node for database diagrams is available in Server Explorer. This seems to be limited to VS 11 with SQL 2012. I can access the diagrams in SSMS and create tables so I know the are there.

and

> Thank you for your feedback. This is a by design change in the product. Diagrams are no longer supported in the new version of the SQL database, so the node is removed when you work with a new SQL server.

Comment: anyway to work around? i rely on database diagram to create table relationships.

Comment: @kndroid Answering your own questions is not only OK, it's *encouraged*!